# Splitting Summation

Tags: summation

While studying for my course, I found following rule in the web (below image).
My professor seems to assume everyone know this, but I don't understand why this works.
It says
$$1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n=
[ 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n/2 ] + [n/2 + \frac{n+1}{2} + \cdots + n]$$
Can you explain how this summation rule works?

$$\large{}\sum_{k=1}^n k= \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}} k + \sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n k$$

Comment: I have trouble understanding the confusion. Are you wondering about what happens when $n$ is not even, so $n/2$ is not an integer?

Answer (score 0):

It's just simply splitting the original sum into two parts.

$\sum_{k=1}^n k\\
=1+2+\cdots+n\\
=(1+2+\cdots+\frac{n}{2})+((\frac{n}{2}+1)+(\frac{n}{2}+2)+\cdots+n)\\
=\sum_{k=1}^{n/2} k +\sum_{k=n/2+1}^n k$

For example, if $n=10$ :

$1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10\\
=(1+2+3+4+5)+(6+7+8+9+10)$